# How to get the corresponding function name by the Fabric trace in Android native?

Tags: android, c

I got the following error in Android(5.0.1) native:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.demo.main
SIGSEGV SEGV_MAPERR 0x0000000000000000
0  libc.so                     0xf75090a8 (Missing)
1  core.so                     0xda4b3d41 (Missing)
2  core.so                     0xda4b401f RTMP_ReadPacket
3  core.so                     0xda4b5c85 RTMP_ConnectStream
4  core.so                     0xda4b1713 stream_push_open
5  core.so                     0xda4b015d initialize
6  core.so                     0xda4b0d1f Java_com_demo_Core_initialize
7  data@app@com.nice.main-1@base.apk@classes.dex    0xe2922c57 (Missing)
```

Here is missing:

```
core.so                     0xda4b3d41 (Missing)
```

I have the source code, so how to get the corresponding function name of **0xda4b3d41** ?